# animate in texlive 17 gives "Missing number, treated as zero."

Tags: animate

I have a new Ubuntu 18 machine, with a fresh install of texlive 2017 from the Ubuntu package.   The following code used to work on earlier texlive versions, but now does not even compile (with pdflatex).  It breaks with "! Missing number, treated as zero" on the \animategraphics command.  Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[autoplay,loop,width=textwidth]{animate}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics{20}{img/64_QAM_}{00}{99}
\end{document}
```

Comment: texlive 2017 isn't really fresh, can't you install texlive 2019?

Comment: I'm reluctant because last time I did that it broke the whole tex system because of having to texlives on the same machine.

Comment: PS: also, because I have to maintain many machines, it's important that I stay with the standard Ubuntu package, even it it's old.   The maintenance overhead of manual texlive installs is too high,

Answer (score 1):

`width=textwidth` is wrong, it should be `width=\textwidth`.

\usepackage[autoplay,loop,width=\textwidth]{animate}

Comment: Of course - thank you!   Weird, because width=textwidth actually worked in Ubuntu 16.

Comment: I successfully tested the example with @Ulrike 's correction on TeXLive-17.

Comment: @KeithB Which TL version is shipping with Ubuntu-16? I would like run a test.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/texlive-base

Comment: Looks like it might be TL2015, but it could actually have been U14 since it last worked.   Anyway, I now have it working after the correction.   I guess the earlier animate version probably just ignored the incorrect option.